# How to Add or Delete tables from database using Yii web application?

Tags: database, web-applications, content-management-system, yii

I am using Yii to create a web application that allows me to view, retrieve, add, and delete information from tables in a MySQL database I have already created.

Is there a way to implement this web app so that I can add or delete tables from the database using the webapp instead of having to login to phpmyadmin?

For example, My database might have 2 tables: "Employee" and "Department". How can I customize my Yii webapp so that I can add a third table "Location" on the fly, using the webapp?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CDBCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#methods) class. It has many database management methods, including [dropTable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#dropTable-detail) and [createTable](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail)

Comment: Wow Thanks, that's good news!! I'll definitely be making use of this.

Answer (score 1):

In Yii there are having [CDbCommand](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#methods) class. With the help of this user can customize database easily. You can create, delete and update table easily with the help of this.

With the help of `dropTable()` method you can easily delete the table from database.

Its help you